# Spring-JPA removes milliseconds when inserting or updating

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my spring boot framework with spring-data-jpa,

when I INSERT or UPDATE with javax.persistence.EntityManager, MySQL database is **inserted without milli seconds**.

in my spring boot framework, I'm working with

spring-data-jpa 2.7.11

mysql-connector-j 8.0.33

hibernate-core 5.6.15.Final

```java
javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;
entityManager.persist(myEntityItem);
```

I tested with Table's columns with
**DATETIME(3) and DATETIME(6)**

**MySQL Table :**

[image]

I tried using
**java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar and java.time.LocalDateTime.**

I also tried with
@CreationTimestamp annotation on my parameter of entity class
and also, manually set each parameter's values.

and every time, I get my TRACE level log with milliseconds included.

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        DREAM_TEST.time_table
        (calendar3, calendar6, java_util_date3, java_util_date6, local_date_time3, local_date_time6, text) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-05-17 10:02:27.685 TRACE 31760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1684285347672,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Seoul",offset=32400000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=30,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2023,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=20,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=17,DAY_OF_YEAR=137,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=10,HOUR_OF_DAY=10,MINUTE=2,SECOND=27,MILLISECOND=672,ZONE_OFFSET=32400000,DST_OFFSET=0]]
2023-05-17 10:02:27.685 TRACE 31760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1684285347672,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Seoul",offset=32400000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=30,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2023,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=20,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=17,DAY_OF_YEAR=137,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=10,HOUR_OF_DAY=10,MINUTE=2,SECOND=27,MILLISECOND=672,ZONE_OFFSET=32400000,DST_OFFSET=0]]
2023-05-17 10:02:27.685 TRACE 31760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2023-05-17 10:02:27.6725819]
2023-05-17 10:02:27.685 TRACE 31760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2023-05-17 10:02:27.6725819]
2023-05-17 10:02:27.685 TRACE 31760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2023-05-17T10:02:27.672581900]
2023-05-17 10:02:27.686 TRACE 31760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2023-05-17T10:02:27.672581900]
2023-05-17 10:02:27.686 TRACE 31760 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [with values set]
2023-05-17 10:02:27.691  INFO 31760 --- [           main] p6spy                                    : #1684285347691 | took 2ms | statement | connection 9| url jdbc:mysql://dreamtest.db:4306/DREAM_TEST
insert into DREAM_TEST.time_table (calendar3, calendar6, java_util_date3, java_util_date6, local_date_time3, local_date_time6, text) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
insert into DREAM_TEST.time_table (calendar3, calendar6, java_util_date3, java_util_date6, local_date_time3, local_date_time6, text) values ('2023-05-17T10:02:27.672+0900', '2023-05-17T10:02:27.672+0900', '2023-05-17T10:02:27.672+0900', '2023-05-17T10:02:27.672+0900', '2023-05-17T10:02:27.672+0900', '2023-05-17T10:02:27.672+0900', 'with values set');
```

But in my database as a result, all the milli seconds are removed

**Result Table:**

[image]

Comment: what is you DB version and vendor?

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem. My DB was **10.4.16-MariaDB-log**  And the problmen was that I was using 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.33' . **The problem was solved when I used 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.1.4'**

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why my original code removes milliseconds but I found other way to solve the problem.

for column such as **create_date** which needs to be set when first **INSERT**,
use

```
'create_date' DATETIME(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(3)
```

and

```
@Column(
        insertable = false
        ,updatable = false
)
private LocalDateTime createDate;
```

for column like **update_date** which needs to be updated each time **UPDATE** executed,

```
'update_date' DATETIME(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(3) ON UPDATE current_timestamp(3)
```

and entity to

```
@Column(updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime updateDate;
```

In this way, each DATETIME columns will be set by database's server time which is better for my situation.